# How to append items into a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a 2D list trends. I open a folder and go through every file in the folder (mostly CSV Files). For every file, I want to put the data into a new slot on the first dimension of the list. For every line in the file, I want to put the data into a new slot on the second dimension of the list. What am I doing wrong here?

```
def showTrends():
    trends = [[]]
    folder = filedialog.askdirectory()
    fileNum = 0
    for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if not "data.csv" in file and not ".gitkeep" in file:
            with open("data/" + file) as csv_file:
                csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
                line_count = 0
                for row in csv_reader:
                    if line_count != 0:
                        trends[fileNum[line_count]].append(row[1])
                    line_count += 1
                csv_file.close()
            fileNum += 1
    print(trends)
```

Comment: Could you add some fake csv files with few lines and the desired result as list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest first creating the inner array, and then appending it to outer array as a whole, like this:

```
trends = []
for file in files:
    file_result = []
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',') 
        next(csv_reader) # To skip the header
        for row in csv_reader:
            file_result.append(row[1])
    trends.append(file_result)
```

This way you don't need to keep the counters at all and your code will be easier to read.

You also don't need to close the file if you are using context manager (`with` statement)

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I am looking for.

Comment: @PicoPlanetDeveloping I'm glad it helped! If it solved your issue, could you please mark my answer as accepted?